# nprgross and nextjs isFinished not resettting

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hello I made a few loading bars one using, nrpgrosses,one with react-nprogress and one using nextNProgress however we use slugs for routing dynamically for items and different categories and it appears the loading bar is not picking up those changes. So if i load category 1 its fine but when i click another category link no loading bar. i worked off from a youtube tutorial but theres not a demo of dynamic pages in there. my only difference is i did not use a store folder for ours like his example shows i console logged is animating and it looks to be hitting true, false, false, true everytime i just do not see a bar loading on the top of the page every time

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJji8_Ywjmc
app tsx

```
 function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 const [isAnimating, setIsAnimating] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

 useEffect(() => {
const handleStart = () => {
  setIsAnimating(true);
};

const handleStop = () => {
  setIsAnimating(false);
};
router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleStop);
router.events.on("routeChangeError", handleStop);
return () => {
  router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
  router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleStop);
  router.events.off("routeChangeError", handleStop);
  setIsAnimating(false);
};
}, [router]);

return (
<ContainerContext.Provider value={container}>
    <Progress isAnimating={isAnimating} />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
</ContainerContext.Provider>
);
}
```

container.tsx

```
export const Container = ({ animationDuration, children, isFinished }) => {
  return (
  <div
  className={`${isFinished ? "opacity-0" : "opacity-1"}`}
  style={{
    transition: `${animationDuration}ms linear`
  }}>
  {children}
</div>
);
};
```

bar.tsx

```
export const Bar = ({ animationDuration, progress }) => {
 return (
  <div
  className="bg-tertiary h-1 w-full left-0 top-0 fixed z-[9999]"
  style={{
    marginLeft: `${(-1 + progress) * 100}%`,
    transition: `transform margin-left ${animationDuration}`
  }}></div>
  );
 };
```

progress.tsx

```
import { useNProgress } from "@tanem/react-nprogress";
import { Bar } from "./bar";
import { Container } from "./container";

export const Progress = ({ isAnimating }) => {
  const { animationDuration, isFinished, progress } = useNProgress({
  isAnimating
 });

 return (
 <Container animationDuration={animationDuration} isFinished={isFinished}>
  <Bar animationDuration={animationDuration} progress={progress} />
 </Container>
 );
 };
```

Comment: throwing my assumption here since the folder is store -> [categoryId] is the router.events.on only able to ready the [categoryId] as [categoryId] and not the url string we get on the www bar

Comment: const { animationDuration, isFinished, progress } = useNProgress({
    isAnimating
  });
looks like isFinished is always true as well. driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.... looks like this was a known issue to my final package decision which is @tanem/react-nprogress found some closed issues followed those around to this example:

https://github.com/tanem/react-nprogress/tree/master/examples/next-router

ended up adding the missing parts and it works :)